# Recover files from .svn folder

Tags: svn

I have a crashed HDD, on which I have a SVN repository with all my work.

My colleague has a working copy of the repo (but not all the data is checked out). He provided me with a big .svn folder.

Is there any way to extract data from the svn folder?

Comment: You need to know the file system you have configured the SVN for. If it is a FSFS file system. Then each revision is nothing but the delta change from the previous revision. Each revision is stored as a revision number file. These are usually object files.  The challenge is to get all the revision the SVN may or may not be able to show you the complete data is any one of the revision is left. These can be found under the db revs folder.

Comment: Him @SiddharthKaul, Thanks for the reply. We are in a bad phase, where all we do is blindly search in some data structures of the HDD. The object files that you are referring, i guess they have this *.o extension, right? Is there any file type that i should search for? Thanks

Comment: No they dont have any extensions they only have type file. All the files in the db dont have any extensions. They just have the type file. Ya if you need extensions to look for this would be difficult. But good luck and lets us know what you did to recover.

Comment: Hi, I am now starting to rebuild the SVN and i start with a question. I received from one of my colleagues, that cloned the repo, one variant of the .svn file from his clone. Do I have any valuable information there?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `.svn` folder into an empty folder.

In that new folder, perform an svn [reversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html). Every file will be restored as the reversion undoes the current state of 'missing' and puts the original files back.

From the command line:

```
svn revert --recursive .
```

---

On a Windows system, it's much easier to use TortoiseSVN. After installing TortoiseSVN, right click on the folder in Explorer and choose `TortoiseSVN -> Revert`. You'll get a dialog like this showing all files missing. Select all the files and click OK:

[image]